# AngularJS function - $Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't find the meaning of the first $scope in this example:

```
app.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
});
```

I know that this is JavaScript and it is supposed to be a parameter for the function but I don't understand what sort of parameter it sets.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the manual https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. Also go through the tutorial on the documentation site ... do each step, well wortth the time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is explained by angularjs documentation.

Comment: Actually I have read the docs several times and stil can't find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

The $scope parameter is being injected into your controller and acts as the "glue" between your controller and view.  So, in your example you would be able to referrence the $scope.message property from your html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="HelloController">
   {{message}}
</div>
```

I would check out the docs and Angular communities on google+.  Good resources to get started.

Comment: Here is a great explanation of scope from the Angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 2):

`A $scope` is a JavaScript object which is used to communicate between controller and view. Basically, $scope binds a view (DOM element) to the model and functions defined in a controller.
[image]

see more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope